# helm generic chart to use as multiple deployments for different installations

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-helm

Lets say I have a Helm chart "ManagementModule", and it has few env variables like as follows.

```
env1:[value1, value2, value3]

env2: "fixValue"

env3: "dynamic"
```

Now, my requirement is as follows:

1. if the target is Customer X environment, create just one deployment with 3 replica may be with name management-module. [this requirement is straightforward but it should work with below case as well]
2. If the target is Customer Y environment, create 3 different deployments with 2 replica each with below env variable.

-- **deployment-name: management-module-1**

```
   env1:[value1]

   env2: "fixValue"

   env3: "dynamic1"
```

-- **deployment-name: management-module-2**

```
   env1:[value2]

   env2: "fixValue"

   env3: "dynamic2"
```

-- **deployment-name: management-module-3**

```
   env1:[value3]

   env2: "fixValue"

   env3: "dynamic2"
```

Second case just wants to have different deployments working on their set of environment values and independent of each other. The chart should support both ways deployments

Can I achieve it through templates/charts? Any suggestions, how we can achieve these 2 set of deployments with single chart?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63528099/generic-helm-chart) solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Answer based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63528099/generic-helm-chart). hence the CW.

You can use `_*.tpl` files to define generic templates, They are located in `./templates/_*.tpl` (`.` being the directory with global Chart.yaml and values.yaml). Also by defaul in helm global values override local values. Solution to this can be found [here](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/5676).

By using these 2 techniques in conjunction you can make generic templates and only use values.yaml to render what you want to render.

For example:

```yaml
# values.yaml
global:
  defaults:
    switches:
      volumesEnabled: false
      ingressEnabled: false
    ingress:
      host: "generic-host.com"
    volumes:
      volumeName: "generic-volume-name"

subchart1:
  defaultOverrides:
    switches:
      volumesEnabled: true
  volumes:
    volumeName: "not-so-generic-name"

subchart2:
  defaultOverrides:
    switches:
      volumesEnabled: true
      ingressEnabled: true
```

Then templates (java is just for grouping templates in one category, you can try to guess in which language my backend microservices are written :) )

```yaml
# ./templates/java/_deployment.tpl

{{- define "templates.java.deployment" }}
{{- $properties := merge .Values.defaultOverrides $.Values.global.defaults -}}
{{*/ generic deployment structure */}}
{{- if $properties.switches.volumesEnabled -}}
volume: {{ $properties.volumes.volumeName }}
{{- end }}
{{*/ generic deployment structure */}}
{{- end }}
```

```yaml
# ./templates/java/_ingress.tpl

{{- define "templates.java.ingress" }}
{{- $properties := merge .Values.defaultOverrides $.Values.global.defaults -}}
{{- if $properties.switches.ingressEnabled -}}
host: {{ $properties.ingress.host }}
{{*/ generic ingress structure */}}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

And then subchart templates

```yaml
# ./charts/subchart1/templates/deployment.yaml

{{ include "templates.java.deployment" . }}
./charts/subchart1/templates/ingress.yaml:

{{ include "templates.java.ingress" . }}
subchart2 has exactly the same includes.
```

In the end we will have:

- subchart1:

  - has deployment
  - volumeName is overriden from local values with "not-so-generic-name"
  - ingress is not rendered at all
- subchart2:

  - has deployment
  - volumeName is default from global values
  - ingress host is default from global values

But I would say that it's a bad practice to generlize to much, because it will make your templates overly complex. In my case I found 2 distinct groups which have nearly identical manifests within them (basically frontend and backend) and made a set of _*.tpl files for each of them and settings default values for each group respectivelly in global values.yaml.